# How to get download URL of image from firebase storage PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, firebase-storage

I am building application using Laravel 5.2, I have connected it with firebase storage to store files there. every thing is working fine, but when I get an image from firebase it only returns below array without any downlabable link

```
"type" => "file"
  "dirname" => "FUEL"
  "path" => "FUEL/Kaleem.jpeg"
  "timestamp" => 1507750905
  "mimetype" => "image/jpeg"
  "size" => "129335"
```

But when I go firebase console it gives me the download link similar to following

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fuel.appspot.com/o/fuel%2F1?alt=media&token=41c1d708-7bc2-41b4-86cf-2536062a261c

Is there any way to get downloadUrl of an image from firebase storage using PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to download with the help of [Google Cloud Storage APIs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/gcp-integration#google_cloud_storage), especially the [PHP SDK](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/storage/storageobject?method=downloadToFile).

Or, you can build your own download URL. For this, you'll need to allow the object to be publicly readable ( `allow read;` ), [percent encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) your file path and the object will be available through a url with the following format: `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/b/<YOUR_BUCKET>/o/<PERCENT_ENCODED_PATH_TO_FILE>?alt=media`

Comment: I just want to do some like below, but it's it's in javascript, I want to do same thing in php.`var storage = firebase.storage();

$scope.getImgUrl = function(file) {
    storage.ref("images/" + file + ".png")
      .getDownloadURL()
      .then(function onSuccess(url) {
        return url;
      })
      .catch(function onError(err) {
        console.log("Error occured..." + err);
      })
  }`

Comment: Did not find any method or property for `getDownloadURL()` in PHP SDK, please help have any idea or any example code.

Comment: The PHP SDK has a [signedURL](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.39.2/storage/storageobject?method=signedUrl) function that lets you create a download URL. Read more about signed URLs [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls)

Comment: signedURL did the job on my side thx!